# Android Web application Viewer from SD card

Tags: android, webview

I can't express myself enough how I don't like to develop anything on Android platform for countless reasons.

So I would like to create simple Android application which will allow me to load index.html file **not** from android_assets folder but from internal storage or even better from SD card.

The goal is to build this application once and don't touch it any more and just edit html/js/css code without recompiling.
I would like to use SQLite database in my web application even if I need to slip it somewhere with root access (it is just for my personal use).

In a perfect world I would expect support for web application in one zip file which can run on any OS, but I will by satisfied with the above.

Can please anybody help me with this project?

Comment: search about `progressive apps` on your favorite search engine

Comment: This might be what I am looking for. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob in Android development, but, here's a suggestion.

You can try hosting your website on a [free hosting](https://infinityfree.net/), after you get a [free domain](https://www.freenom.com/en/index.html?lang=en) and then load it all in an Android app using WebView.

Comment: This is not very good solution. It should be offline. Once I had it done with web server running on device, but that is also not the best :)